# Find a range of rows containing specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet in Excel where the E column contains the velocity of a vehicle. The first few rows have 0 velocity until the vehicle starts moving. I want to find the range of rows at the start of the sheet where the vehicle is in idle and remove them, as I have no real reason to keep these rows

I found this code to find the range of rows where a specific text is stored in one of the cells:

```
Private Sub DeleteIdleRows()

    Dim idleStartRow as Long, idleEndRow as Long
    With ActiveSheet
        idleStartRow = .Range("E:E").Find(what:="0", after:=.Range("E3")).Row
        idleEndRow = .Range("E:E").Find(what:="0", after:=.Range("E3"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

End Sub
```

The code gives no errors, but it finds the absolute last instance of 0, and not the last 0 in the first "set". Is there a way for me to narrow down this search function to stop as soon as the next instance is not 0?

Comment: Instead, use:  `.UsedRange.Autofilter 5, 0` it will filter all the cells which contain 0.

Comment: I may be doing this wrong or missing something, but how can I use this to specifically only delete the 0 velocity rows at the start of the sheet and not in the middle/end of it?

Comment: Worth mentioning the `FIND` will remember the last settings that were used (through VBA or the UI) - so if you searched Values it will find the 0 in 30, if it was last used to search Formula it will find the 0 in 30 and the 0 in =B30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub DeleteIdleRows()
    Dim idleStartRow As Long
    Dim idleEndRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    idleStartRow = 0
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            If Range("E" & i).Value2 = 0 And idleStartRow = 0 And IsEmpty(Range("E" & i).Value2) = False Then idleStartRow = i
            If Range("E" & i + 1).Value <> 0 And idleStartRow <> 0 Then
                idleEndRow = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox idleStartRow
    MsgBox idleEndRow
End Sub
```

I have modified your code little bit and is working fine. Also note that in your formula when you are using `find` function, it will also return the row even if the value contains zero (Example: 30)